# Boeing 747 Autopilot PID Controller

Tags: flight-controls, autopilot

For a personal flight simulator project, I am creating my own custom Boeing 747 classic series. I have about 50% of the project complete at a level of detail nearly equivalent to study-level flight simulators. I hope this is the right place to ask this.

Currently I am writing an autopilot that utilizes PID controllers. PID's are new to me so I am still learning a lot. I will do my best to explain what I need. If I am incorrect somewhere, please correct me!

The first controller I am attempting to write is for Heading Select, which will cause the autopilot to bank the airplane such that it will obtain and then maintain a selected magnetic compass heading. I have a lovely NASA paper, formed by collaboration with NASA and Boeing, that gives excruciating detail of the gains used for all autopilot modes. I also am referencing David Allerton's Principles of Flight Simulation for some basic examples.

According to NASA, for all lateral (roll) autopilot modes, the following fixed attitude and rate gains are used:

$\frac{\delta_a}{\phi}=3.2\frac{deg}{deg}$ and $\frac{\delta_a}{\dot \phi}=3.6\frac{deg}{deg/sec}$

This part already has me a small bit confused, but according to a later page, these are the gain values for roll angle and roll rate, respectively. The autopilot is limited to 12 degrees of aileron and 26 degrees of aileron deflection per second.

Source: https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19730001300/downloads/19730001300.pdf
Pages 543 and 553

My best guess as to what these were, were the P and D values for an aileron controller (P value of 3.2 * bank error, D value of 3.6 * roll rate) but I am not sure of this. Testing the PID controller with this method, the aircraft does indeed roll to assigned headings, but the roll rate can be very high and does not seem well controlled.

The whole controller looks like this. The gain value of 2.83 is directly from page 553 listed above for the gain value of Heading Select mode on bank angle calculation.

$0.0016175\mathit{V}+0.110375 $ minimum $0.353$ maximum $1.0$ - This is a multiplier on the gain for heading select mode, proportional to true air speed (V)

$2.83$ multiplied by that True Air Speed modifier is the gain for Heading select, $K_p$

$K_p$ * heading error = target bank angle, $\phi$, maximums $\pm 30$ degrees left or right

Target Bank angle - Current Bank = Bank error

Bank error * $0.1$ = Target Roll Rate, $\dot \phi$, maximums $3$ $deg/sec$

Target Roll Rate - Current Roll Rate = Roll Rate Error

Bank error * $3.2$ = Proportional aileron deflection $P$

Roll Rate * $3.6$ = Derivative aileron correction $D$

$P+D$ = Total aileron deflection, maximums $\pm 12$ degrees

So that leaves me with figuring out how to get the deflection rate (how quickly the autopilot moves the ailerons). I am not sure how to calculate that with what I have and I find that my autopilot is completely ignoring the maximum roll rate information, accelerating very quickly into a bank.

Comment: Paging @Terry to the white courtesy phone. Terry to the white courtesy phone for a 747 question, please. Sadly, that probably won't work as I haven't seen him around in quite a while, but he'd be your guy - he spent about a decade as a 747 pilot/co-pilot and wrote a fair bit of software about it and for other aircraft. I'm sure someone else will give you a good answer too.

Comment: @FreeMan indeed Terry hasn't been around for a while. His own website says he hasn't updated his 'I-am-still-alive-date' in 10 days. I hope he's doing ok.

Comment: That's a shame... Any idea where I could potentially reach Terry these days?

Comment: @ChristopherHelton I think you are missing the rate control loop. Normally you would first have an roll angle PID, which determines the amount of roll rate command (which you can additionally limit, resulting in a slower response in roll) and then another PID which determines the amount of aileron deflection in order to follow the aforementioned roll rate command